# Can a fact be proven in infinitely many ways?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question

My question is, if something is genuinely true, take for example '$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational', does there exist an infinite amount of unique proofs for that statement?
The inquiry comes from there being several different ways to solve mathematical statements like Pythagorean's theorem or the square root of two's irrationality and so on.

This may be a dumb question and not involved with any specifics but I have had this in the back of my mind for a while now and I am curious as to what smarter people have to say (even if it is striking the question down).

Comment: Define "*unique*". If you mean truly different proofs, then you wouldn't know infinitely many proofs even if they existed, since you'd need some finite time to read/parse each proof. If you count minor variations as differences, then you could for example start a proof with "*assume the expansion of $\sqrt{2}$ in base $b$ is eventually periodic*", and construct a "*differrent*" proof for each integer $b \gt 1$.

Comment: There are formalizations of "different ways of proving" in terms of different paths deductively connecting premises to conclusions that cannot be deformed into one another by trivial steps, see [When are two proofs of the same theorem really different proofs? on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/3776/51484). Depending on complexity of the proof system and which steps are designated "trivial", there could be infinitely many distinct deformation classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a definitive way to answer this question considering "infinitely many ways" to prove a given mathematical fact seems to be a stretch. We *can* say there are many ways to prove something. For example, there are over one hundreds proofs for Gauss's Law of Quadratic Reciprocity. For a specific example, Eisenstein proves this law with geometry and the greatest integer function to count lattice points within a given triangle inscribed within a rectangle. George Andrews wrote a textbook on number theory, but his proof differs slightly from Eisenstein's, using an inscribed hexagon rather than a triangle and not using the greatest integer function at all.

Mathematicians can find many ways to prove something, but more than likely it will be a small variation similar to the example previously described.